# Is the heat equation (e.g. 2D) solvable without boundary conditions? Or are the boundary conditions always present?

Tags: heat-equation

Is the heat equation (e.g. 2D) solvable without boundary conditions? Or are the boundary conditions always present?

I've been puzzled a bit, since it seems that w/o boundary conditions there's no evolution from initial state. But this is what I'm trying to clarify.

Comment: The boundary conditions are required to fix the solution... If you don't set the boundary conditions the solution is not unique. Unless there is no boundary...

Comment: I think there is a convolution integral solution for the heat conduction problem, at least in 1D, that only needs the initial condition.

Comment: Think physically: if you don't know whether someone is heating, say, a brick from a side, how can you predict its temperature? That's what boundary conditions are about.

Comment: @Benjamin_Gal The convolution integral is in the whole space... In general we do need the boundary conditions.